# How do I load a matrix from a .txt file in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix that looks like this in a txt file:

```
[[0.26263508 0.89992943 0.62171512 0.20750958 0.21195397 0.97217826
  0.61573457 0.05643889]
 [0.33188798 0.32016444 0.92051048 0.75572024 0.20247452 0.37400282
  0.10935296 0.63343081]
 [0.87017165 0.7283508  0.80314653 0.80094718 0.74024014 0.16330332
  0.76579785 0.75177055]
 [0.2629302  0.59727507 0.60866212 0.29746334 0.54587234 0.43876005
  0.75007362 0.89742691]
 [0.05300406 0.83342629 0.19291691 0.83372532 0.98122163 0.7815009
  0.59635085 0.9700382 ]
 [0.69259902 0.42779514 0.04766533 0.62205107 0.71423376 0.85045446
  0.31985818 0.15338853]
 [0.26947509 0.41946874 0.87206754 0.35849082 0.94756447 0.59001803
  0.41028535 0.85643487]
 [0.87299386 0.70986812 0.87212445 0.30309828 0.31214338 0.33387522
  0.52875374 0.75712628]
 [0.51605143 0.64374971 0.37821579 0.77055732 0.12504581 0.75814223
  0.87462081 0.97378988]
 [1.27346865 0.73175293 1.35820425 1.08405559 0.97660218 1.31912378
  0.62859619 0.94765808]]
```

When I try to read it into a program using

```
inputMatrix = np.loadtxt("testing789.txt", dtype = 'i' , delimiter=' ')               
print(inputMatrix)
```

My problem is that the `[` and `]` in the file are strings that cannot be converted to int32. Is there an efficient way to read in this matrix?

Comment: Why did you save the array that way?  One way or other you'll have to clean it up.

Comment: What generates this text file? If you also wrote the code that writes it, you should consider writing it in a less ambiguous and easier to parse format. Also, will the text always contain a 2D array, or could this be some arbitrarily shaped array?

Comment: With that format (the `str` display of a numpy array), there's a chance that the text has `...`, indicating missing portions.  There's no way of recovering that data.

Comment: Plus the line breaks. You probably intended to get 10 rows from your example, but there are 20 lines.

Comment: Plus the random (not strictly random: it occurs when the last decimal place of the last float of a row is 0, and not printed) spaces before the closing `]`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing the matrix to a file like this:
`myFile.write(str(matrix))`,

Write it like this to automatically have it formatted:
`np.savetxt(fileName.txt, matrix)`

One last thing: Load the matrix from the txt file like so:

`inputMatrix = np.loadtxt("testing789.txt", dtype = 'f' , delimiter=' ')`

Where `dtype = 'f'` is used instead of `i` so that the matrix values are not rounded.